# Can't display unicode 0x0332 with iText

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, itext

### Setup

I'm using iText 5.3.0 and Fedora 17, testing with PDF readers llpp and evince. My IDE is Eclipse Indigo r2. My terminal is urxvt with the same font as used in the PDF.

### Problem

Other unicode characters show just fine. Listing 11.3 in the iText book shows just fine. But trying to get an X̲, X with [an underline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underline#Unicode), like `"X\u0332"` won't show up on a PDF. I can log the string to the terminal with `System.out.println` and it works just fine. Here's an example of what I'm trying:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
  Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("fnord.pdf"));
  document.open();
  FontFactory.register("fonts/mplus-1mn-regular.ttf", "mplus");
  Font font = FontFactory.getFont(
    "mplus",
    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
    BaseFont.EMBEDDED,
    12
  );
  String s = "X\u0332";
  System.out.println(s);
  document.add(new Paragraph(s, font));
  document.close();
}
```

I found an ancient, possibly related, [email from Paulo Soares](http://www.mail-archive.com/itext-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00991.html) saying "character combination must be done before presenting the text to iText".

I'm not sure what this means, or how to do it, or if it's still relevant.

### Expected / actual

I expect: a PDF with an X with a line underneath the X, ie X̲.

I get: a PDF with an X, no line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my pdf viewers aren't displaying right. I copied and pasted the text output from the pdf viewer, copied into my terminal (where I've verified this character(s) work), and see the X̲.

Copy and pasting works in

- llpp with mupdf version a606f714258677688c67e9561b87cc70f9e9b6b0
- adobe reader 9.5.1

But does not work in evince 3.4.0 (poppler 0.18.4). The copied text is just a plain X.

So it seems that iText is not at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your character is a nonspacing one, [see here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/332/index.htm)

**EDIT** Page says it connects on left and right, so my answer is not very useful :(

Comment: So my string should be "X\u0332X" and I should see "XX" with the first underlined? (which doesn't work, just trying to understand)

Comment: [This](http://www.unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html) confusing FAQ might clear it up. As far as I understand it's like a generic accent mark.

Comment: Not sure, here is a [list of fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/332/fontsupport.htm) that support this character. Is your font included?

Comment: The M+ font here is not in the list, but it works in both Eclipse's console and my urxvt terminal. Times New Roman from MSTT core fonts has the same behaviour, and *is* in the list.